# Time complexity of struct

Tags: c++, struct, time-complexity

I'm using struct in C++ for a Hospital Management System to hold patient records and use it to add, list, search and delete records like,

```
struct details{
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    int age;
    char gender[7];
    int phone;
    char doc_name[40];
};
details d[100];

void add()
{
   counter++;
   cout<<"\n\t\t\tRECORD NUMBER: "<<counter;
   cout<<"\n\t\t\t1.FIRST NAME: ";
   cin>>d[counter].first_name;
   cout<<"\t\t\t2.LAST NAME: ";
   cin>>d[counter].last_name;
   cout<<"\t\t\t3.AGE: ";
   cin>>d[counter].age;
   cout<<"\t\t\t4.GENDER: ";
   cin>>d[counter].gender;
   cout<<"\t\t\t5.PHONE: ";
   cin>>d[counter].phone;
   cout<<"\t\t\t6.DOCTOR: ";
   cin>>d[counter].doc_name;
   char add_another;
   cout<<"\n Add another record (Y/N)?:  ";
   cin>>add_another;
   if(add_another == 'Y')
     add();
   else
     menu();
}
```

I want to know the time complexity of using struct. Will using linked lists or map or vector be a better choice to hold records?

Comment: This is non-sensical. With the `struct` (btw, why not use a `class` if you're using [tag:c++]?), you're defining your composite data type. A vector, map, list, or whatever will be the abstract container for organizing records of this datatype. It would replace the simple static **array** (`d[100]`) you're using here ... **not** your `struct`.

Comment: So, don't get this wrong, but before even thinking about algorithmic complexity and the like, please first learn the language you're using, e.g. what is the difference between a type definition and a container holding objects of the defined type.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Why not class? It involves more typing.

Comment: @juanchopanza sure, if you know it will stay a "dumb" data object forever, `struct` is fine.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Makes no difference. A `struct` and a `class` can be as clever or dumb as each other.

Comment: @juanchopanza go tell, I know this. Would you really define a `class` including functionality as a `struct`? The "public by default" of a `struct` is meant for dumb data objects where it makes sense to access the data members directly. (and, of course, to be roughly compatible with [tag:c])

Comment: Use a database, let the database manage the record storage and indexing.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, I would. Because it makes no difference. Usually, if most members are public, I'd go for `struct`. Otherwise, `class`. It is just coding conventions in the end.

Comment: How will you be indexing (searching the data)?  Specifically what are the primary key fields?  This will determine the data structures you will need.

Comment: @juanchopanza well it indeed *is*. Wanting to follow good OO principles, I'd still argue "private by default" is the only way to go. But different opinions on this are ok, of course.

Comment: I recommend you overload `operator>>` within the structure to make input easier.  You may also want to overload `operator<<` to output a textual representation of the data structure (like comma separated).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am completely with juanchopanza. OO principles arent the only principles and not every thing has to be encapsulated in a class. Actually I do not see anything related to OO in this code. And especially when pointing out that it is non-sensical to ask for the "time-complexity of a struct", imho it is non-sensical to insist that it would be better to use a class instead of a struct.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use a vector of structures to hold the data.

Next, I suggest you create `std::map` to use for searching the database.  The map will be of the type:
`std::map<key_type, unsigned int>`

Where `key_type` is the data type of the field you want to search for.
`unsigned int` will be the index into the vector.

The `std::map` variables are called *index tables*.  This allows you to sort and efficiently search for records without modifying the data vector.

Also, if you can, replace the `char *` fields with `std::string`.  The `std::string` type is easier to work with, especially with `std::vector` and `std::map`.

The best path of development will be to use an existing database and not write your own.  Remember, you have development and testing time.  The existing database are already developed and tested; you only have to **access** them; not develop them.